# Most efficient way to manipulate multiple images

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ram

I am writing an image stitching program and currently have it working but want to start over and optimize it. I wanted to put all the images into a C++ `vector<Mat>` so I ca create other vectors so all the different layers I produce are at the same vector location. I wanted to know if it is smart to load every image into a vector or if it is smarter to load in the address location of the vector. Not sure how heavy the images are on RAM and looking for some insight. Each image will have several passes going over it from keypoint detection, bundle adjustment, homography calculations, stitching, and blending.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Each image will take the following amount of RAM in bytes: bytes-per-sample x width x height x number-of-channels (plus a few bytes to store some information such as the dimensions)

Grayscale images have 1 channel and color images have 3, images with transparency have 4, but you can have multispectral images with many more channels.

Images can have 1 or more bytes per sample depending of the precision. 1 byte means values from 0 to 255 and it is quite common, but 2 or 4 bytes per sample are also possible.

Each image can easily occupy a few megabytes, so it depends how many images you have, how big they are and if you really need to store all steps or not.

I usually try to reuse the images for intermediate steps and I try to save RAM (specially if you process one by one and you store the result in disk).